# Creating a permanent background in pygame

Tags: python, background, pygame

I have a program where I am using mouse controls to move objects. When the objects move, the program resets the screen to solid white so that there are no trails of the object using:

```
screen.fill(255,255,255)
```

What I am trying to do now is have the background a created background I made in a method.

```
black = (0,0,0)
brown = (218,134,10)
white = (255,255,255)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,white,(0,0,1000,600))

first =pygame.draw.rect(screen,brown,(150,150,50,400),0)
second = pygame.draw.rect(screen,brown,(450,150,50,400),0)
third = pygame.draw.rect(screen,brown,(750,150,50,400),0)

first_out = pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(150,150,50,400),2)
second_out = pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(450,150,50,400),2)
third_out= pygame.draw.rect(screen,black,(750,150,50,400),2)
```

How can I make my background the background that refreshes every time an object is moved?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than drawing directly on the screen surface, you should create a new surface, let's call it `background_surface`.

By doing so, you will only have to *draw* the background once (at the very beginning of your application) and any blitting afterwards will be done a lot quicker, since no  `pygame.draw.xxx` is being done.

To fill the screen surface with `background_surface`, you'll just use `screen.blit()`.

---

A quick snippet:

```
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
background_surface = pygame.Surface((WIDTH, HEIGHT))

# do all the drawings on the background surface
background_surface.fill((255, 255, 255))

while application_running:
    # processinput
    # update objects
    # draw everything
    screen.blit(background_surface, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: This is just giving an error saying background_surface is not defined

Comment: That is caused by `background_surface` being out-of-scope. Shouldn't be much trouble to fix that error. The code I provided was just an example.